# example of highchart for mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

friends I'm new to `highchart` ,need your help to create chart in `MVC 4` ,I write the code on Home controller like...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
    .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false })
    .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column })
    .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Membership Overview" })
    .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new[] { "Paid Members", "Active Members", "Retained Members", "New Members", "Lapsed Members" } })
    .SetYAxis(new YAxis
    {
        Min = 0,
        Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Total Members" }
    })
    .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +''; }" })
    .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions { Bar = new PlotOptionsBar { Stacking = Stackings.Normal } })
    .SetSeries(new[]
               {
                   new Series { Name = "Total", Data = new Data(new object[] { 441, 441, 22, 30, 610 }) }
                });


        return View(chart);
    }
}
```

now I don't understand how to render it on `index.cshtml` page.

Answer (score 0):

Your Index.cshtml page should look something like this to display your chart.

```
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts

@{
   var chart = Model;
}

if(Model != null) {
    @(chart)
}
```